# How do I save myself from Khorne?

Tags: chaos-in-the-old-world

Chaos in the Old World is a game about stomping all over your opponents, either by dominating regions or killing them off! Khorne is particularly good at the latter, requiring to spill much blood to the blood god to win. This was an issue for me, playing as Nurgle as my precious lepers kept being killed and harshing my ability to lay down corruption. I can imagine it'd be an issue for anyone else too.

How can I protect myself from Khorne? What is his weakness, and how can I exploit it?

Comment: My feeling is honestly it's tzeentch's job to keep khorne in check, if he doesn't do it, he won't win either.  we house rule that in 3 player games khorne is out.

Comment: @Affe in the 3 player game I had previous to that we did the same, and it worked nicely. Poor Tzeentch was doing his best to keep Khorn in check but it wasn't enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everybody needs to team up on Khorne, at least at the start. If he gets powerful early, he's hard to stop.

Khorne's biggest weakness, as I see it, is that he goes first. Early on, you should be able to spend some low-cost cards and force him to make his moves first. Then, put your lepers elsewhere. If he gets on the same space as you, see if you can move off it.

With this practice, my groups generally manage to keep Khorne in check. You'll still lose a few lepers, but as long as he's not double-ticking his dial, you should be able to tick yours or dominate for points. Later on, he'll be a spread-out unstoppable killing machine, but usually the game ends before that will cause you undue worry.